# SQLAlchemy - simple select statement

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

**Background:**

I am very new to SQLAlchemy and it seems to be fairly confusing as to how I should be selecting things.

I have a table in my mysql database which is called genes, where I have gene_id, gene_description, and gene_symbol

**What I want to do:**

All I want to do is a simple select query:

```
Select * from Genes
```

But I seem to be confused as to how we shall achieve this

**Here is what I have done:**

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
import csv
import pandas as pd

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://root:toor@localhost') # connect to server
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=engine)
engine.execute("USE TestDB")

genes = sqlalchemy.table('Genes')
s = sqlalchemy.select([genes])
engine.execute(s)
```

**The problem:**

```
ProgrammingError: (_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `Genes`' at line 2") [SQL: u'SELECT  \nFROM `Genes`']
```

Also is there some type of "intellisense" where I can just do something like gene_table = engine.Gene. If I am not mistake there is a way to do this with mapping but it didn't work for me

EDIT:
This may help:

[How to automatically reflect database to sqlalchemy declarative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290162/how-to-automatically-reflect-database-to-sqlalchemy-declarative)

Comment: You didn't specify any rows in the table, so the query issued has a syntax error due to the empty expression list. You should either define columns (either manually or through reflection), or, if you actually want `SELECT * ...`, do `select(["*"]).select_from(genes)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So we can use reflection and do not have to create classes explicitly, but if we want speed we can create them using something like sqlautocode as stated here:

[Reverse engineer SQLAlchemy declarative class definition from existing MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425412/reverse-engineer-sqlalchemy-declarative-class-definition-from-existing-mysql-dat)

Also there is an issue with mysql databases where it will give an error that looks like the following: (taken from bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/1909/reflection-issue-with-mysql-url-with-no)

```
SNIP...
File "/opt/buildout-eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.6.4-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 1927, in __init__
    self.reflect()
  File "/opt/buildout-eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.6.4-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 2037, in reflect
    connection=conn))
  File "/opt/buildout-eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.6.4-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1852, in table_names
    return self.dialect.get_table_names(conn, schema)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/opt/buildout-eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.6.4-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 32, in cache
    return fn(self, con, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/buildout-eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.6.4-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 1791, in get_table_names
    self.identifier_preparer.quote_identifier(current_schema))
  File "/opt/buildout-eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.6.4-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 1517, in quote_identifier
    return self.initial_quote + self._escape_identifier(value) + self.final_quote
  File "/opt/buildout-eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.6.4-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 77, in _escape_identifier
    value = value.replace(self.escape_quote, self.escape_to_quote)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

This is resolved by adding a database name (the one you are using) as follows:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://USER_NAME:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1/DATABASE_NAME', pool_recycle=3600) # connect to server
```

**I used this to connect correctly:**
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html
and this:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html

This also may help:
[How to automatically reflect database to sqlalchemy declarative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290162/how-to-automatically-reflect-database-to-sqlalchemy-declarative)

**My code finally looks like this:**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = automap_base()

# engine, suppose it has two tables 'user' and 'address' set up
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://root:toor@127.0.0.1/TestDB', pool_recycle=3600) # connect to server

# reflect the tables
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

# mapped classes are now created with names by default
# matching that of the table name.
Genes = Base.classes.Genes

Address = Base.classes.address
#Start Session
session = Session(engine)
#add a row:
session.add(Genes(Gene_Id=1,Gene_Symbol = "GENE_SYMBOL", Gene_Description="GENE_DESCRIPTION"))
session.commit()
q = session.query(Genes).all()
for gene in q:
    print "This is the Gene ID {},\n This is the Gene Desc {},\n this is the Gene symbol {}.".format(gene.Gene_Id,gene.Gene_Description, gene.Gene_Symbol )
```

Comment: I just got the `NoneType` error too, I'd say it could be worth adding it to the question itself :)

Comment: Just as a reference you MUST have a primary key to do the automapping. Otherwise it wont automap:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765681/sqlalchemy-automap-does-not-create-class-for-tables-without-primary-key